# puppet apply vs puppet agent -t

Tags: puppet

I am new to puppet and while going through puppet courses, I found one person using **'puppet agent -t'** command to configure an agent node while in another course, the instructor using **'puppet apply'** command.

What is the difference between these two commands?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

These are:

- [`puppet apply`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/man/apply.html) - applies or "executes" Puppet code on the local machine.
- [`puppet agent -t`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/man/agent.html) also sometimes written `puppet agent --test` - calls the Puppet Agent to retrieve a catalog (compiled Puppet code) from a Puppet Master, and then applies it locally and immediately.

Note that `-t` is badly-named, and it may originally have been intended for "testing" but in fact it is not a "test" mode at all, but will make changes to your machine.

See also `puppet agent --noop` for the real "test" (dry-run) mode.